Cannot find module Lambda authorizer
I'm using AWS CDK and I have created an API-GATEWAY and the lambdas work but now I'm creating an authorizer and I'm having problem with this.
In my stack I have the following to create all lambdas less authorizer lambda:
const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(
        this,
        `${lambdaHandlerPath}-handler`,
        {
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
          handler: `handler`,
          entry: `${lambdaCodePath}/${lambdaHandlerPath}.ts`,
          bundling: {
            externalModules: ['aws-sdk'], // Excluir módulos de AWS SDK
            minify: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            target: 'es2020',
            platform: 'node',
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
            assetHash: `${lambdaCodePath}/${lambdaHandlerPath}`, // Just for local environment
          },
          environment: {
            GRANT_TYPE: process.env.GRANT_TYPE || 'defaultGrantType',
            CLIENT_ID: process.env.CLIENT_ID || 'defaultClientId',
            CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET || 'defaultClientSecret',
            REDIRECT_URL: process.env.REDIRECT_URL || 'http://localhost',
            JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'gggggg',
            API_GATEWAY_JWT_SECRET: process.env.API_GATEWAY_JWT_SECRET || 'asd'
          },
          timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30)
        }
      );

For authorizer lambda I have:
const authorizerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'AuthorizerLambda', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/auth/lambdas/v1'),
  handler: 'AuthorizerLambda.handler',
  environment: {
    JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
  },
});

// Crear RequestAuthorizer
const authorizer = new apigateway.RequestAuthorizer(this, 'Authorizer', {
  handler: authorizerLambda,
  identitySources: [
    apigateway.IdentitySource.header('Cookie'),
    apigateway.IdentitySource.context('path'),
  ],
});

The stack file is:
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { routes } from '../../src/AllRoutes';

export class ApiGatewayStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'ApiGateway', {
      restApiName: 'MyAPIGateway',
      description: 'API Gateway with multiple microservices integration',
    });

    const apiVersions = new Map<string, apigateway.Resource>();
    
    routes.forEach((route) => {
      const version = route.version || 'v1';
      if (!apiVersions.has(version)) {
        const versionResource = api.root.addResource(version);
        apiVersions.set(version, versionResource);
      }

      const versionResource = apiVersions.get(version);
      const lambdaHandlerPath = route.lambda.fileName;
      const lambdaCodePath = route.lambda.codePath;

      const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(
        this,
        `${lambdaHandlerPath}-handler`,
        {
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
          handler: `handler`,
          entry: `${lambdaCodePath}/${lambdaHandlerPath}.ts`,
          bundling: {
            externalModules: ['aws-sdk'], // Excluir módulos de AWS SDK
            minify: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            target: 'es2020',
            platform: 'node',
            tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json',
            assetHash: `${lambdaCodePath}/${lambdaHandlerPath}`, // Just for local environment
          },
          environment: {
            GRANT_TYPE: process.env.GRANT_TYPE || 'defaultGrantType',
            CLIENT_ID: process.env.CLIENT_ID || 'defaultClientId',
            CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET || 'defaultClientSecret',
            REDIRECT_URL: process.env.REDIRECT_URL || 'http://localhost',
            JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'gggggg',
            API_GATEWAY_JWT_SECRET: process.env.API_GATEWAY_JWT_SECRET || 'asd'
          },
          timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30)
        }
      );

      const integration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaFunction);
      const method = route.method.toLowerCase();

      let methodOptions: apigateway.MethodOptions = {};

      if (route.authorizer) {
        // Crear Lambda para el authorizer
        const authorizerLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'AuthorizerLambda', {
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
          code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('src/auth/lambdas/v1'),
          handler: 'AuthorizerLambda.handler',
          environment: {
            JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET as string,
          },
        });

        // Crear RequestAuthorizer
        const authorizer = new apigateway.RequestAuthorizer(this, 'Authorizer', {
          handler: authorizerLambda,
          identitySources: [
            apigateway.IdentitySource.header('Cookie'),
            apigateway.IdentitySource.context('path'),
          ],
        });

        methodOptions = {
          authorizer: authorizer,
          authorizationType: apigateway.AuthorizationType.CUSTOM, // Tipo de autorización
        };
      }

      versionResource
        ?.resourceForPath(route.path)
        .addMethod(method, integration, methodOptions);
    });
  }
}

All lambdas have its own routes for that is dynamic:
export const authRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    version: 'v1',
    path: 'login',
    method: 'POST',
    lambda: {
      fileName: 'LoginLambda',
      codePath: `src/${moduleName}/lambdas/v1`,
    },
  },
];

But the authorizer lambda doesn't have route because I have to add to the endpoints that they need authorization but I got this error:
2024-11-26T02:56:21.462Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'AuthorizerLambda'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'AuthorizerLambda'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)","    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"]}
26 Nov 2024 02:56:21,616 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=
26 Nov 2024 02:56:21,619 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=43eb0b99-7944-43ad-ae4c-6b9af78d1f49
26 Nov 2024 02:56:21,620 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke DONE failed: Sandbox.Failure

Lambda authorizer failed to invoke successfully:
Exception on /v1/api-gateway/test [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 706, in _request_handler
    raise ex
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 689, in _request_handler
    self._invoke_parse_lambda_authorizer(lambda_authorizer, auth_lambda_event, route_lambda_event, route)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 787, in
_invoke_parse_lambda_authorizer
    lambda_auth_response = self._invoke_lambda_function(lambda_authorizer.lambda_name, auth_lambda_event)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.129.0/libexec/lib/python3.13/site-packages/samcli/local/apigw/local_apigw_service.py", line 622, in _invoke_lambda_function
    raise LambdaResponseParseException

Authorizer lambda is located in:

